# C++ Multi-Threaded Operation Slower than Single Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am carrying out a 3D matrix by 1D vector multiplication within a class in C++. All variables are contained within the class. When I create one instance of the class on a single thread and carry out the multiplication 100 times, the multiplication operation takes ~0.8ms each time.
When I create 4 instances of the class, each on a separate thread, and run the multiplication operation 25 times on each, the operation takes ~1.7ms each time. The operations on each thread are being carried out on separate data, and are running on separate cores.
As expected, however, the overall time to complete the 100 matrix multiplications is reduced with 4 threads over a single thread.

My questions are: 
1) What is the cause of the slowdown in the multiplication operation when multiple threads are used?
2) Is there any way in which the operation can be sped up?

EDIT:
To clarify the problem:
The overall time to carry out 100 matrix products does decrease when I split them over 4 threads - threading does make the overall program faster.
The timing in question is the actual matrix multiplication within the already created threads (see code). This time excludes thread creation, and memory allocation & deletion. This is the time that doubles when I use 4 threads rather than 1. The overall time to carry out all multiplications halves when I use 4 threads. My question is why are the individual matrix products slower when running on 4 threads rather than 1.

Below is a code sample. It is not my actual code, but a simplified example I have written to demonstrate the problem.

Multiply.h

```
class Multiply
{
public:
  Multiply ();
  ~Multiply ();

  void
  DoProduct ();

private:
  double *a;
};
```

Multiply.cpp

```
Multiply::Multiply ()
{
  a = new double[100 * 100 * 100];
  std::memset(a,1,100*100*100*sizeof(double));
}

void
Multiply::DoProduct ()
{
  double *result = new double[100 * 100];
  double *b = new double[100];

  std::memset(result,0,100*100*sizeof(double));
  std::memset(b,1,100*sizeof(double));

  //Timer starts here, i.e. excluding memory allocation and thread creation and the rest
  auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();

  //matrix product
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
    {
      double t = 0;

      for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k)
    t = t + a[k + j * 100 + i * 100 * 100] * b[k];

      result[j + 100 * i] = result[j + 100 * i] + t;
    }

  //Timer stops here, i.e. before memory deletion

  int time = std::chrono::duration_cast < std::chrono::microseconds > (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now () - start_time).count ();

  std::cout << "Time: " << time << std::endl;

  delete []result;
  delete []b;
}

Multiply::~Multiply ()
{
  delete[] a;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
void
threadWork (int iters)
{    
  Multiply *m = new Multiply ();

  for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)
  {
    m->DoProduct ();
  }
}

void
main ()
{
  int numProducts = 100;
  int numThreads = 1; //4;
  std::thread t[numThreads];

  auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now ();

  for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    t[i] = std::thread (threadWork, numProducts / numThreads);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    t[i].join ();

  int time = std::chrono::duration_cast < std::chrono::microseconds > (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now () - start_time).count ();

  std::cout << "Time total: " << time << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Remember that starting a thread has a cost. Make sure there is enough work per thread to justify that cost. Also beware of false sharing and don't start more threads than you have cores/hyperthreads or the cost of switching between threads goes up.

Comment: @drescherjm I am building with the -O3 flag, and sorry, numProducts is 100 - that's just a mistake in copying onto here

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is just a simplified example with smaller matrices. When I scale up the matrix size I get the same effect. Just to clarify, the overall time does decrease with number of threads - I am just curious as to why each individual product takes longer despite having no shared data

Comment: Try to use a thread pool and see the results

Comment: Memory allocation is slow, and they serialize the code.

Comment: You are leaking memory like a sieve  on each iteration of the loop.  Would that have an effect on your findings?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Sorry, I am deleting the memory, I just missed out those lines on here!

Comment: What happens when you try 2 threads?

Comment: @drescherjm 2 threads is in-between. The individual matrix products are slower than 1 thread, but faster than 4 threads. The overall time is faster than 1 thread, but slower than 4 threads.

Comment: There are numerous potential reasons. My guess here is that with a single thread, you keep reallocating the same two blocks of memory and thus every thing stays in cache. With multiple threads, the memory is spreading out due to chaotic allocation timing, and causing cache hits

Comment: You do understand that `std::memset(b,1,100*sizeof(double));` is not setting all of the doubles to 1.0 right?

Answer (score 0):

Async and thread calls are quite time expensive compare to ordinary function calls. So pre-launch  threads and create a thread pool. You push your functions as tasks and request the thread pool to tether these tasks from the prority-queue.

The tasks could  be set with priorities to execute in proper order  to avoid use and hence delays arising due to use of mutexes and locks

You are launching too many threads  , keep it below the maximum allowed by your system to avoid bottlenecks.